# kafka node is not able to connect to kafka client on shared cluster

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

my code is as shown below:

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const Producer = kafka.Producer;
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: process.env.CLOUDKARAFKA_BROKERS});
const producer = new Producer(client);
producer.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('it has started');
});

producer.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('kafka error is ' + err);
});
```

But somehow it prints the error `kafka error is BrokerNotAvailableError: Broker not available`

Comment: Can you hit the brokers on port 9092 from the machine you're running this code?  Try `nc -z [kafka-broker] 9092`